# Why vim doesn't insert cyrillic symbols properly in Ex mode?

Tags: encoding, vim, cyrillic, ex

To make changes in several files I use the following script:

```
echo search('publications.html"') | normal o<li><a href="./book_series.html">Книжные серии</a></li>
echo search('collections.html"') | d
echo search('photo.html"') | d
wq
```

Then I do `for file in *.html do; vim -e $file < script; done`

As a result a string "^Z=86=K5 A5@88" is inserted instead of "Книжные серии".
All html files as well as the script itself are utf-8 encoded, and no other problems with Cyrillic revealed.
What's going on?

Thanks in advance for any comment!

Comment: Is *Vim* in utf-8 encoding? Check what ":set encoding?" tells you.

Comment: Are you sure encoding is utf-8 when launching Vim with the `-e` flag? The help states that when Vim starts in ex mode, *and the -s flag is given*, that Vim skips reading the .vimrc and other things. Perhaps for some reason Vim is skipping that in your case also? You can try using "-S script" instead of "-e ... < script" to start Vim normally.

Comment: FWIW I tested the first line of your script in my Vim, and it seems to work as intended, not as you report.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, the -S option really helps! My locale is en_US, and the default encoding in vim is latin1 (e.g. it encodes such a normal mode script written by the -W option), so may be this messes the cyrillic when in Ex mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the vim_use mailing list response to this same question, [multibyte characters are not handled in Vim's ex mode](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_use/EkmujDkg5sU/discussion).

Thus, the solution is to not use ex mode at all.

Instead of using:

```
vim -e $file < script
```

Use the -S flag to run the script outside of ex mode:

```
vim -S script $file
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tell Vim to interpret your script as utf-8, even if all the encodings are correct.

Try inserting this line at the top of your script:

```
 scriptencoding utf-8
```

Comment: Same effect, and I need to press return after the process is complete (in my case it closes itself).